# Deleting EMPTY S3 BUCKET

Tags: amazon-s3, buckets

I am trying to delete an EMPTY S3 Bucket.

I have deleted everything, and if I go inside of the bucket in S3 browser it says:
"The bucket 'blankety.blank.blank' is empty"

YET, when I try to delete the bucket it gives the error:
"The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. Please delete all objects and folders inside of the bucket and try again."

I have deleted plenty of buckets, and I'm familiar with the process. ???  Not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting error message that bucket is not empty, that means it may have some objects in the bucket. You are also getting message the bucket is empty by the using tool. that is showing the result of normal listing. bucket if you have ever set versioning enable on that bucket then it may be possible that there are some version objects exist in the bucket.

Now List version objects and if found any version objects then delete all version objects and then try to delete the bucket again.

After deleting all object as well as version objects you can delete the bucket.

Comment: I am doing the same, but the version with delete markers did not delete. Any way to delete versions with delete markers? @TejKiran

Answer (score 0):

Just install the eclipse, and aws tools. 
then just remove all the buckets you desire. Im having the same problem and this resolve my problem